# Javascript subclass of XMLDocument doesn't work

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

I've tried to create prototypes(I think thats what it's called) & perform inheritance in Javascript. Hopefully it follows the conventions of Javascript.

What should be changed so that it works & so thats its correct javascript coding? The code doesn't compile/work right now

I am attempting to create a Cross Browser XML parser. So I try to "subclass" the XMLDocument object, although I am unsure if that object even exists, I am trying to subclass the object (returned from XMLHttpRequest() object) when I call the function xmlHttp.responseXML;

One important thing is I want to stick to native Javascript & steer clear of EcmaScript 5 for now until I learn the native javascript ways to create prototypes & perform inheritence.

```
  // I intend to use the XMLHandler object like so:
  var xml = XMLHandler("myXMLFile.xml");
  var slides = xml.getElementsByTageName("slide");

  function XMLHandler( /*string*/ xmlFilePath )
  {
     this.getXMLFile = function()
     {
        return this.xmlFile;
     }

     this.xmlFile = xmlFilePath;
     this.parseXMLFile( this.xmlFile );
  }


  XMLHandler.prototype             = new XMLDocument();  // is this enough to make the object inherit from the XMLDocument
  XMLHandler.prototype.constructor = XMLDocument;        // make XMLHandler call the base class constructor when created


  if ( window.XMLHttpRequest )
  {
     XMLHandler.prototype.parseXMLFile = function( xmlFilePath )
     {
        this.xmlFile = xmlFilePath;
        var xmlHttp  = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", this.xmlFile, false);       //Open the file using the GET routine
        xmlHttp.send(null);                             //Send request
        this = xmlHttp.responseXML;                     //this object holds/is the document information now
     }
  }
  else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) // if the current browser is an old version of IE
  {
     XMLHandler.prototype.parseXMLFile = function( xmlFilePath )
     {
        this.xmlFile  = xmlFilePath;
        var xmlHttp   = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlHttp.async = "false";  // keep synchronous for now
        this          = xmlHttp.load( this.xmlFile );
     }
  }
```

Comment: "The code doesn't compile/work right now" - what is the exact problem you are having? What isn't working?

Comment: Initialise the "class" by prefixing the `new` keyword: `var xml = new XMLHandler("myXMLFile.xml");`

Answer (score 0):

1. Javascript *IS* EcmaScript.  *Anything* you learn for *any* version under *either* name would be valuable.  Don't try to "steer clear".
2. By the same token, don't be at all shy about picking up jQuery or Dojo if you think they might help with your task.
3. Please *do* "steer clear" of any preconceived notions of "inheritance", or of what exactly "cross platform" may or may not mean.
4. Just focus on your GOAL.  What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish.  Not "How" (e.g. with "inheritance"), but "*WHAT*" (e.g. "I want to parse this XML file so I can display some information in a web page").

IMHO .. PSM

PS:
Your Javascript "isn't compiling"???  What exactly do you mean?

PPS:
If you're coming from C++ or Java, some of your preconceptions about "inheritance" - or, for that matter, "object oriented", might actually be more harmful than good.  Get a copy of Douglas Crockford's Most Excellent "Javascript: The Good Parts" ;)